# How is querying a data warehouse different than querying a database?

Tags: database, data-warehouse

Say I have a data warehouse like BigQuery, RedShift. I store data which is fit for online analytical processing (OLAP). Similarly suppose I have a database like MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server which has some data fit for online transaction processing(OTLP).

What are the different parameters on which querying a data warehouse and a database would be different?

Comment: a data warehouse is also a database, are you attempting to compare a "transactional db" to a warehouse? even so your question is so general it has no specific answer, it would need a few chapters maybe

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question nevertheless I think the following can help you make your desicion:
1. How much data you have Vs relational features 
2. Cloud solution Vs on premesies
3. Payment models (derived from 2) for example bq model is per scan while other is per storage